# Why can't I join on minecraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm at a hotel and I have Internet, obviously because I'm on this website. But anyways I can't join my friends game. Both of our local server option is on. I don't understand why it's not working. 0.75

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Is your friend also online and gone through the login page?

Answer (score 5):

This is because the hotel's WiFi has something called Wireless Isolation within SSID disabled and this is why you can't find each other's server. Wireless Isolation within SSID is when computers or devices can see other computers connected via LAN but not able to see other computers connected via WLAN.

Answer (score 3):

WiFis other than those that are generated by private routers frequently have settings which disable any multiplayer usage. This is really unavoidable, if you have an iDevice, you can set up a Personal Hot Spot. Otherwise, if you're in a hotel, just wait it out until you get home.